# Authenticate to Azure Web App Service from Azure Dev Ops

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1

My team is looking at migrating from our on premise Team Foundation Server to Azure Dev Ops (In the cloud). We have a ASP.Net core 2.1 web app on our intranet that responds to a POST from a service hook when work items are updated, and then does some calculations and updates the work item using the C# SDK.

before we can migrate, I need to refactor that code so that it is internet facing, and I assumed a Azure web app service would provide us with what we need quickly, and with a solid authentication mechanism. My hope was that Azure Devops would allow us to authenticate with the app service using our federated AD identities, and got excited by seeing the (as of 1/4/2019 [undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts)) Azure App Service service hook type!

[image]

That is not the case, as this service is only for deploying my web app to the app service. So I have to use the the generic `Web Hook` , which apparently only accepts basic auth...

[image]

Using the answers from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296648/basic-authentication-in-asp-net-core) I can get a working web app published that uses basic authentication using third party middleware (which all scream at me to not use them and to implement a real authentication solution). But I do not know how to do that and have it integrate with Azure Dev ops.

Neither the (Azure Devops specific) documentation on how to create a [PR server with Node.JS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?toc=/azure/devops/extend/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/extend/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts), or using [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?toc=/azure/devops/extend/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/extend/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts) mention anything about authentication (or SSL for that matter) and I am at a lost as to how to proceed next to ensure our web app is secure.

My question is, how have you created a secure web app that is able to integrate with TFS/Azure Devops service hooks?

Comment: You could use the Web Hook to call an Azure Function using Basic Auth that then calls your Web service using your desired authentication.

Comment: @MartinBrandl, I cannot find any documentation/examples of how to implement basic auth with Azure functions. I found a SO question asking about it and the Op answered it themselves saying they parsed the Authorization header of the request, which is essentially what I am doing in my Asp.Net app right now. The other answer says no, that is not possible. From this, it seems like using an Azure function as a middle man would just complicate the solution, without providing me a direct benefit (since I still need to ensure I am implementing the basic auth logic correctly)

Comment: hm, you are right - if you are able to modify your existing ASP.NET API, you can do the auth there, Azure Function won't give you any benefits. Then that is probably the way to go...